# How can I set the default option of dropdown while using choices library?

Tags: javascript

I am using [Choices library](https://joshuajohnson.co.uk/Choices/) for dropdown. What I need to do is to retain the selected value of dropdown and show it as soon as the page reloads before submitting. Right now I am able to store the value using `sessionStorage`. But how can I show it in the `choices` dropdown as the default option once the page reloads? I read the documentation but not able to figure out how to pass the default value.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.myDropdown').forEach(selectBox => {
    choicesElements = new Choices(selectBox, { addItemText: ['Yes'], sortFn: (a, b) => a < b  } );
    selectBox.addEventListener('change', () => {
       // code to populate choices
    }
}
```

```
let marks_dropdown = document.querySelector('.myDropdown');
marks_dropdown_id.addEventListener("change",function() {
    var choices_item_selectable = document.querySelector('.choices__item.choices__item--selectable')
    storeSelectedItem(choices_item_selectable.innerText);
}

function storeSelectedItem(innertext) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('innertext', innertext);
}

let innertext = sessionStorage.getItem('innertext');
if (innertext) {
    let new_choices_item_selectable = document.querySelector('.choices__item.choices__item--selectable');
    new_choices_item_selectable.innerText = innertext;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `.value` of the `<select>` element, like you usually would?

Comment: Yes. I have. If I use that then the required value is prepended to the list. So it is not shown before clicking. Only after clicking it is shown as the first element in the dropdown.

Comment: Can you add relevant code to your question? Ideally as [mre].

Comment: @Lax_Sam The Choices library you are talking about is this https://joshuajohnson.co.uk/Choices/ ? Aside of this, you are not setting a `value` to your dropdown options neither the [`selected`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp) attribute. This last one is, maybe, what is needed to show the `option` as pre-selected.

Comment: Yes. I am using the same library.

Comment: I got it. I just had to add `selected` option as mentioned by @FlavioCysne.

Comment: @Lax_Sam Great! Could you please add an answer with the running code, so other users can see the solution? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue as below.

```
assignChoicesElements = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.myDropdown').forEach(selectBox => {
    choicesElements['some-key'] = new Choices(selectBox, { sortFn: (a, b) => a < b });
    selectBox.addEventListener('change', () => {
        let reqdValue = selectBox.value;
        if(reqdValue != '') {
            storeSelectedItem(reqdValue);
        }
    });
    let elementsObject = {};
    document.querySelectorAll('unMarked').forEach(unmarkedElement => { 
       elementsObject['some_key'] = //whatever value to be stored;
    });
    choicesElements['some-key'].clearStore();
    choicesElements['some-key'].setChoices(getPossibleCombinations(elementsObject), 'value', 'label', false);
};

getPossibleCombinations = (jsonObject) => {
  var possibleCombinations = {}
  Object.entries(jsonObject).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    var newPossibleCombinations = possibleCombinations
    Object.entries(possibleCombinations).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      let newValue = value
      newPossibleCombinations['some-value'] = newValue
    })
    newPossibleCombinations['key'] = ['some-value']
    possibleCombinations = newPossibleCombinations
  })
  var formatedPossibleCombinations = []
  Object.entries(possibleCombinations).forEach(([key, value]) => {
   // Here is the change. Get the stored value and while creating the list of values, add selected: true to the value if it is found in sessionStorage.
    let sessionStorageValue = sessionStorage.getItem('stored_item')
    if (sessionStorageValue) {
      formatedPossibleCombinations.push({ label: key, value: value, selected: true })
    }
  })
  return formatedPossibleCombinations
}

function storeSelectedItem(value) {
  sessionStorage.clear();
  sessionStorage.setItem('stored_item', value);
}
```

This code is more than required for the question. But I have added it just in case if anyone finds it useful.