# Count number of times addEventListener is called in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a script as below:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let all_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown')
    all_buttons.forEach((ele) => {
        ele.addEventListener('change', () => {
            showSpinner(true);
            let id = ele.dataset.id
            let value = ele.value
            fetchAPICall(id, value)
            showSpinner(false); // Problem is at this line
       })
    })
}

showSpinner = (flag) => {
  let spinner = document.querySelector("#spinner");
  if (spinner && flag) {
     spinner.classList.add("show");
  } else if (spinner && !flag) {
    console.log('dont show');
    spinner.classList.remove("show");
  }
}

fetchAPICall = async (id, value) => {
  let my_url = document.getElementById('table').dataset.fetchUrl
  my_url += "?id=" + id + "&choice=" + choice
  try{
    const resp = await fetch(my_url, { credentials: 'include' })
    const response = await resp.json()
    if(response.success) {
      document.dispatchEvent(someEvent);
    } else {
        if (alert('Oops !!! Something went wrong. Check Your Internet connection or try refreshing the page')) {
        }
    }

  } catch(err){
      notifyError(err)
      alert('Oops !! Something went wrong. Check Your Internet connection or try refreshing the page')
    }
}
```

What I need to do is to call that `showSpinner` function after all the the loops of `addEventListener` of all changed elements. How can I do that? `fetchAPICall` is `async`. So here the spinner should be shown till all the calls to fetchAPICall are completed. Until then it should be visible.

Comment: Are you looking for answer to the question on how to capture all the change events in one and then show spinner? Instead of doing it for all the change events separately?

Comment: I'm guessing that your question is how to show the spinner while the `fetchAPICall` is not done yet because it's a synchronic method. Is that true?

Comment: Yes. It is true. @harry joy

Comment: Yes it is true. @mosh feu

Comment: From reading your code, I assume as well that you want to show the spinner while 'loading/chaning' and then hide it again when it is done. Welcome to the world of javascript. Callbacks and promises are here exactly for these kinda problems.

What you need is to use these async tools of your fetch method and then you can hide it when the fetch is done (your fetch function must return a promise or accept a callback function. see the first answer.

Comment: it's still not clear what you're trying to achieve. `call that showSpinner function after all the the loops of addEventListener of all changed elements` addEventListener operations are instant and will all finish immediately before even running your fetchAPICall functions. Pretty sure this is not what you are trying to do. Do you just want to show the spinner if ANY fetchAPICall is currently in progress, and hide it otherwise?

Comment: Yes. I want to show spinner till all ajax calls are complete.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `fetchAPI` method is returning a `Promise` (if not, please add it to your question), the `change` handler should looks like that:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let all_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown')
    all_buttons.forEach((ele) => {
        ele.addEventListener('change', () => {
            showSpinner(true);
            let id = ele.dataset.id
            let value = ele.value
            // finally because you want to hide the spinner in any case (even for error)
            fetchAPICall(id, value).finally(() => {
                showSpinner(false); // Problem is at this line
            });
       })
    })
}
```

Comment: It is not working. Again it is being executed on the first value of `fetchAPICall`. I have edited the question.

Comment: I don't understand. When a dropdown (any of them) changed, you're displaying the spinner. So you want it to remain there until all the rest of the dropdowns will changed too?? By the way, `fetchAPICall` does return a `Promise` because you declared it as `async`.

Comment: The drop-down values are generated by combinations of various values from the database. For eg: if the data from the database is { 1: 4, 2: 8 } then the values of drop-down will be [4, 8, 12] with their IDs stored in dataset like this: ['1', '2', '1,2']. Then these values along with their IDs are sent to the fetch call on clicking a value from drop-down.

Comment: That's fine. But, your code says: I have some elements (what tags are they? `input`? `select`? ..) with the class `dropdown`. When each of one of them has changed, display the spinner, then call the API and when the request is finished, hide the spinner. Is that correct? Maybe showing also the html will help to better understanding..

Comment: It is a `select` tag and I have used `choices` library to create it. The options are generated as shown in the answer in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59622040/7773783

Comment: Let's put it that way, what approach is yours? https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-uohzne?file=index.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205592/discussion-between-lax-sam-and-mosh-feu).

Answer (score 0):

An approach to solve the problem is, we can create an array of indexes of elements which processed in the loop and after all of them a call the updateSpinnerStatus whenever the fetch API called and returned successfully and if the length of all buttons equals to the **length** of processed function, then showSpinner will execute.

```js
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            let all_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
            let allButtonsProcessed = [];
            all_buttons.forEach((ele, index) => {
                ele.addEventListener('change', () => {
                    showSpinner(true);
                    let id = ele.dataset.id
                    let value = ele.value
                    
                    fetchAPICall(id, value).then(() => {
                      allButtonsProcessed.push(index);
                      
                      updateSpinnerStatus();
                    });
               })
            });
            
            
        }
        
        updateSpinnerStatus = () => {
           if(all_buttons.length === allButtonsProcessed.length) {
              showSpinner(false);
            }
        }

        showSpinner = (flag) => {
          let spinner = document.querySelector("#spinner");
          if (spinner && flag) {
             spinner.classList.add("show");
          } else if (spinner && !flag) {
            console.log('dont show');
            spinner.classList.remove("show");
          }
        }

        fetchAPICall = async (id, value) => {
          // logic
        }
```

Comment: The spinner is not being removed if I execute this code.

Comment: Still the spinner is not being removed.

Comment: Actually inside `updateSpinnerStatus` the length of those two is not same. That is why it is not being removed.

Comment: If all of them processed successfully, the spinner will be removed, if you can the spinner removes anyway, you can move the updateSpinnerStatus to the finnaly prototype of promise.

Answer (score 0):

I added a map that will contain your currently running fetch calls. Every time fetch call starts or ends, it will, respectively, set its running status to true or false, can call `updateSpinner`. `updateSpinner` will show spinner if there is ANY call still in progress and remove it if there is none

```
// this map will contain currently running fetch calls
const runningFetchCalls = {}

fetchAPICall = async (id, value) => {
  let my_url = document.getElementById('table').dataset.fetchUrl
  my_url += "?id=" + id + "&choice=" + choice
  try{
    // assuming id is unique across buttons
    // add id to the map of currently running fetch calls
    runningFetchCalls[id] = true
    const resp = await fetch(my_url, { credentials: 'include' })
    const response = await resp.json()
    if(response.success) {
      document.dispatchEvent(someEvent);
    } else {
      if (alert('Oops !!! Something went wrong. Check Your Internet connection or try refreshing the page')) {
      }
    }

  } catch(err){
    notifyError(err)
    alert('Oops !! Something went wrong. Check Your Internet connection or try refreshing the page')
  } finally {
    // remove it from the map
    runningFetchCalls[id] = false
  }
}

updateSpinner = () => {
  // if any fetch call is currently running (value is truthy),
  // next statement will return true
  if (Object.values(runningFetchCalls).some(item => item)) {
    showSpinner(true)
  } else {
    showSpinner(false)
  }
}
```